# Modify HTML source on-the-fly with xPath using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Let say I'm having a HTML source, something like :

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://msn.com">MSN</a>
```

Is there any way for me to modify this HTML source with xPath using Javascript : find all anchors, prepend text to them and show the new HTML source using an alert box?

```
<a href="http://google.com">Visit Google</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com">Visit Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://msn.com">Visit MSN</a>
```

Comment: What does "without modifying the frame" mean? What does "alert the new HTML source" mean? (possibly to show the new HTML source using an alert box?)

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I have edited my post. Hope it's clear enough

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a job for XPath. You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` to get the anchors, then iterate through them and do the modification you have in mind. Is there a particular part of that process that you need help with?

Comment: No the source is a string. Not any HTML elements so I think of using xPath.

Comment: @user: it sounds like you're saying the HTML source has not been parsed into a (DOM) tree. In that case, XPath cannot effectively work on it; it's designed to select nodes from a tree. To operate on strings, you could use regexp substitution, though it would be awkward, depending on whether all your links are as simple as the examples.

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the `innerHTML` of some element (e.g. an invisible `<div>`) to your HTML source string. This would cause the source to be parsed into a DOM tree. Then you could use `myDiv.getElementsByTagName('a')` or jQuery `$('a', myDiv)` to find the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need full power of [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) for making several transformations, you could use something like [sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html).

I think you might be confusing [xPath expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Expressions) with [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), so for that case I would recommend to use the following [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) code:

```
// Put a script tag including jquery.js here

<div id="container">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="http://msn.com">MSN</a>
</div>

<script>
    $("a").prepend("Visit ");
    alert($("#container").html());
</script>
```

Regards.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Tho I think the OP is saying the links are not in a DOM, so jquery won't help.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no".

XPath is a method for selecting elements in a DOM. It can also be used to read attributes and calculate values, but it can't be used to modify the DOM. You might be getting confused with XSLT, which uses XPath expressions to select elements and can return a modified document. You could use a generic XML document, then use different XSL style sheets using XSLT to generate different documents in various languages, say HTML, XML, postscript, and so on.

In any case, why would you bother with XPath in this case? There is a *document.links* collection that requires simple property access, no function calls or evaluating XPath expressoins. You can change simple text content by assigning to the W3C [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) or proprietary MS [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property (again, simple property access rather than function calls):

```
function modLinks() {

  var links = document.links;
  var i = links.length;

  while (i--) {
    setText(links[i], 'Visit ' + getText(links[i]) );
  }
}

// Simple helper functions, can be made faster and more robust
// but sufficient for an example. 

function getText(el)  {

  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;

  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}

function setText(el, text)  {

  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    el.textContent = text;

  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    el.innerText = text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, XPath doesn't work effectively with unparsed strings.

So one approach would be to set the innerHTML of some element (e.g. an invisible ) to your HTML source string.

This would cause the source to be parsed into a DOM tree. Then you could use myDiv.getElementsByTagName('a') or jQuery $('a', myDiv) to find the links. (You could even use XPath `.//a`, but why use a more complex tool when a simpler one will do?)

Then once you've modified the strings, e.g. as somebody said using `jQuery $('a', myDiv).prepend("Visit ");` you could output the modified HTML by retrieving the `innerHTML` property of the invisible `div`.